# how do I get notified when the query sortable drop operation ends?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

How do I get notified when an item in the jquery sortable drop operation ends?

Comment: You mean a callback...? You're gonna have to give us more information than that.

Comment: Yes, a callback.  When someone drops an element from one column to another as in http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists, I would like to be notified

Comment: Um, it's right there Options > stop

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#event-stop <-- Add `stop: function(event, ui) { ... }` to your `.sortable({})` . Give it a try, and if you run into any trouble, let us know.

Comment: Try http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#event-over  OR http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#event-receive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i have done complete bins for above query.

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp9e

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">
    </span>
    Item 1
  </li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">
    </span>
    Item 2
  </li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">
    </span>
    Item 3
  </li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">
    </span>
    Item 4
  </li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">
    </span>
    Item 5
  </li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">
    </span>
    Item 6
  </li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">
    </span>
    Item 7
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
#sortable{
  width:50%;
}
#sortable li{
  list-style:none;
}
#sortable li span{
  display:inline-block
}
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(function() {
    $("#sortable").sortable({
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            alert("Sorting Stopped..!");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp9e